# Catching exception on Environment.Exit()

Tags: c#, exit, exit-code

I need to return an exit code of 1 after my Main functions ends. However I have an other thread that never ends `(while(true))`. So I managed to call *Environment.Exit(1)*. But I got some exception when disposing com objects...

For several reasons I can't change the other thread code. What do you guys advocate to do?

May I catch the exception coming from the com object disposing? Do I have an other option for returning an exit code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to: attach to ProcessExit event to do any last chance cleanup or... do a Thread.Abort on the thread to allow it to finish before exit.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit +=
delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process Exit");
};
Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test 1");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Terminating t1");
}
}));

Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test 2");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Terminating t2");
}
}));

t1.Start();
t2.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
t2.Abort();
t2.Join();
Environment.Exit(1);
```

Comment: Thread.Abort is widely regarded as bad practise- http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation. Also the question states that they can't change the other thread code.

Comment: @RicardOD: It is precisely because the worker thread can not be changed that you have to use Thread.Abort an not the volatile bool flag technique suggested in the article you link to. Also using Thread.Abort in a process shutdown is probably not so bad especially if the worker thread is catching the ThreadAbortException outside the while(true) loop.

Comment: @RichardOD Using `Thread.Abort` is a terrible idea except for the one case it was designed for - during an AppDomain unload, to abort threads that don't behave. Process termination also means an AppDomain unload, effectively, so this is actually a "not as terrible as the others" use case for it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Environment.ExitCode = 1;
```

However; if the other thread is not a background thread, you will *need* it to exit in order to end the process (the exit code is meaningless until the process exits).

Comment: I already tried this but seems that the uncatched exception (occuring during the environment.exit) erases this value.

Answer (score 0):

you can kill proccess by writting this code
Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess() myProcess.Kill()

or 
Environment.exit(1)
is best method for kill all processes

http://www.zhakkas.com/affiliates/idevaffiliate.php?id=542